# Django-cms problem

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm setting up a website using django-cms and when I open up the add page view in the admin, I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/cms/page/add/

Invalid block tag: 'csrf_token'
```

What could be the problem? I'm using Django 1.1. BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Add `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to MIDDLEWARE in settings.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
]
```